# static const member of a struct is not defined

Tags: c++

Using an 03 standard-compliant compiler (safety-critical variant of gcc-3.3.2). 
The standard says that static member objects must be defined (9.4.2 (4)). It also states that the one-definition rule holds, but no diagnostic is required (9.4.2 (5)). Is the following code valid?

```
struct fred
{
    static const int JOE=1;
    int m_joe;
    fred() : m_joe(JOE) {}
};
```

That is, there is ***no*** "static const int fred::JOE;".
I ask because we have a case (apparently) where a static const int in a template class was never defined, and the code worked in some contexts, but not others. I replaced the static const int with an enum, and it worked in all cases.
Were we definitely in the Land of Undefined Behavior?

Comment: Could you post the actual code that was broken?

Comment: I think you've answered your own question. I cannot see anything relevant to add: you already point out where the standard says your code is invalid, but no diagnostic is required. You're right about that.

Comment: This basically shows it (http://codepad.org/d8kSVZwN). There are several things not to like about it, but we were seeing cases where set() wasn't working on enumerations beyond 32. I made both NUM_BITS_IN_BYTE and m_event_size enums, and the problem went away.

Comment: Or alternatively, you could have provided a definition, as you indicate in the question. Either would work.

Comment: Providing a definition for a template class data member is problematic...

Answer (score 1):

A `static const int` defines a compile-time constant; I'm afraid I can't refer to a specific part of the standard. The only time you need a definition for it is if you try to take the address of it or create a reference. If you use an enum instead, the compiler will create a temporary variable for you when you need a reference.

```
struct test
{
    static const int one = 1;
    enum { two = 2 };
};

void printint(const int & i)
{
    cout << i << endl;
}

int main() {
    printint(test::one);  // error
    printint(test::two);  // no error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but this is just wrong. A `static const int` defines something that *can* be used as a compile-time constant, but unless it *is* used as a compile-time constant (which especially before C++11 is far less often than you would expect), it still needs a definition. If in your example `printint(const int & i)` is changed to `printint(int i)`, the call `printint(test::one);` *still* requires a definition of `test::one`. Compilers are not required to complain about a lack of a definition, though, so whether that would give an error depends on the implementation.

Comment: @hvd if that is so then why is the syntax of initializing at the declaration even allowed? It appears to work in gcc: http://ideone.com/CJ7265

Comment: It was sort of an oversight in the standard, that's why C++03 relaxed some of the requirements, and C++11 relaxed them further, but many compilers that *don't* have any C++11-conforming modes (including older versions of GCC) really do have cases where an explicit definition would be required where you might not expect it. They simply implemented what the standard required, and it was occasionally easier for those implementations to sometimes generate code that happened to require a definition.